# I don't see any errors in my parallel integral calculation program, but I get segmentation fault (code 139), how can I fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, mpi, integral

I wrote a program for parallel calculation of the integral using the Manager-workers strategy.

I get *error 139(segmentation fault)*, but I don't understand where I could have made a mistake.

I get *error 139(segmentation fault)*, but I don't understand where I could have made a mistake.

I get *error 139(segmentation fault)*, but I don't understand where I could have made a mistake.

**Here is my code**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"
using namespace std;

double f(double x){
return sqrt(2+pow(x,2))/((1+cos(2*x))*sqrt(1-x));
}


double adaptIsol(double left, double right, double eps)
{
double mid,h,Iold,Ileft,Iright,I; 

h = (right - left)/2; 
mid =(right + left)/2; 
Iold = h * (f(left) + f(right)); 
Ileft = h * (f(left) + f(mid))/2; 
Iright =h * (f(mid) + f(right))/2; 
I = Ileft + Iright; 

if(fabs(Iold - I) < eps)
    return I;
else
{     
    Ileft = adaptIsol(left, mid, eps/2); 
    Iright = adaptIsol(mid, right,eps/2); 
    cout<<Ileft+Iright<<endl;
    return Ileft + Iright; 
} 
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
int rank, size, n = 100000, s = 0;
double a = 0, b = 1.0, eps = 0.0001, I = 0.0, h, t;

MPI_Status st;

//start working with MPI
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

h = (b - a)/n;
n --;

if(rank == 0) {//manager proc
    while(s != (size -1)){
        double Islave;
        MPI_Recv(&Islave, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &st);
        I += Islave;
        MPI_Send(&n, 1, MPI_INT, st.MPI_SOURCE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        if(n >= 0)
            n --;
        else
            s++;
    }
}
else {
    int m;
    while(1) {
        MPI_Send(&I, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv (&m, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &st);
        
        if(m >= 0){
            I = adaptIsol(a + h * m, a + h * (m + 1), eps * h / (b - a)); 
        }
        else break;
    }
}
if(rank == 0) cout <<"Integral value: " << I <<endl;
MPI_Finalize();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
[enter image description here][1]}
```

*Please help me find the error.*
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/olSIu.png

Comment: first, make sure a non MPI version of this program is working.

Comment: You are right, I checked not the MPI program - the same problem, I think an error in the calculation of the integral, but I still can not understand what is wrong I calculate(

Comment: Infinite recursion? Try increasing the stack size and see if it helps.

Comment: I increased, unfortunately did not help